# How can I show only specific parts of a text line in C#

Tags: c#

Hello sorry if the answer for this is already out there somewhere but I did not find it, or did not understand it.  What I have to do is I have a list box in visual studio (C#) and in this list box are some options to click on.

PinturaV $100

PinturaA $105

PinturaE $115

Lijas_Ag $112

Solvente $101

If I select a line for example PinturaA $105 from the list box in a text box that I have it should show only 105. Then if I select for example Lijas_Ag $112, the text box should show...

105

112

And so on until I press the total button and it would give me the total.
My problem is having just the numbers appear on the text box.  I coded so that the program can read the line selected and tell me where the space is located but I don't know if this was even needed to be able to get the number into the text box.  I have no Idea how to do this.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I left some pics in case that helps.

Thank You

[main selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abGZ7.png)

[Code I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj5vC.png)

Comment: You could use regex and match on `\$(\d+)`

Comment: Please include the relevant code needed to create a [MCVE] in your actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Regex` to get your desired output. You need to apply `Regex` in your `ListBox` `event`. Please check below for `Regex` & `C#` example.

Regex:

```
\d+
```

Above `Regex` will give you all `digit` from your `string`

CODE C#:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your others code & logic

    //string data = "PinturaV $100";
    string data = listBox1.Text;
    textBox1.Text = Regex.Match(data, @"\d+").Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the selected text is `PinturaA $105` .. you can use regular expression (or) string library method to get only the numbers like

```
string str = "PinturaA $105";
string val = (str.IndexOf("$") > 0) 
              ? str.Substring(str.IndexOf("$"), str.Length - str.IndexOf("$")) 
              : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a regex:

```
var oldtext = "Solvente $101";
var newtest = Regex.Match(oldText, "\\d+$").Groups[0].Value;
```

The variable `newtext` will contain the digits.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regex and just do

```
    var item = "Solvente $101";
    var val = Regex.Match(item, @"\$(\d+)").Groups[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are OK and will probably work.  But just so you know, the typical way to handle this sort of thing is to put the data you want in the ListItems' `Value` property and the text in the `Text` property, like this:

```
private void PopulateListBox1()
{
    listBox1.Add(new ListItem("100","PinturaV $100"));
    listBox1.Add(new ListItem("105","PinturaA $105"));
    listBox1.Add(new ListItem("115","PinturaE $115"));
    listBox1.Add(new ListItem("112","Lijas_Ag $112"));
    listBox1.Add(new ListItem("101","Solvente $101"));
}
```

And then get the `Value` instead of `Text`, like this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue; 
}
```

As you can see this is far, far simpler than parsing the string returned by `ListItem.Text`.

Comment: Thank You all for your help.  I used various suggestions to give me what I needed. John Wu, I understand your way of doing this but for some reason I could not get it to work it would give me some error, but I do see the logic and the simplicity in the way you told me.  One last question. I am supposed to have all the ones I selected show up in the text box and stay there while selecting more. Ex.. 115 and if select another like 101 the text box should keep 115 and also under it show 101 and so on.  Any Ideas on how to do this?  I have set multi-line to true on text box. What am I doing wrong?